# jquery ajax [object Object] [object Object] output in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code using ajax:

```
$("#keyword").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
    if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {
        $.get( "./lib/data_siswa_ajax.php", { keyword: keyword, sekolah: $("#sekolah").val()} )
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('#results').html('');
            var results = JSON.parse(data);
            $(results).each(function(nama, value) {
                $('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
            })

            $('.item').click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $('#keyword').val(text);
            })

        });
    } else {
        $('#results').html('');
    }
});
```

Output in div result:

```
[object Object]

[object Object]

console.log:

[{"nama":"Sakkel Krista Afrentino"},{"nama":"Abdul Rahman Alfikkry"}]
```

Help me.. How do I fix this?

Comment: In this case `key` is the index of the current item from the array and `value` the item itself. So you just have to use the property `nama` from the object instead of the object itself -> `.append('<div class="item">' + value.nama + '</div>')`

Comment: It is because you are getting whole object in single, means it is nested object. You have to iterate using each loop to get the actual value.Replace  value with 'value.nama'.

Comment: thanks its work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I guess you should change:

```
$('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
```

To:

```
$('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value.nama + '</div>');
```

Since value is a json object and name is the only property of the object.

Comment: That's not an _json object_ but an ordinary object. [JSON](http://json.org) is a data-interchange format.

Answer (score 1):

In the `foreach`, the second parameter is the single object of the collection of objects.

If you want to show the json string you can use `JSON.strigify(value)`, but if you want to access to a json property or value, you will need to navigate `value` json for instance:

```
value.name
```

it will print 'Sakkel Krista Afrentino' in the first iteration, which is the content of the first position on the object